# Update model from database is not updating

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, edmx

I am working on a solution with .edmx file

The environment is:

- VS 2013
- Entity Framework 5.0.0.0
- .Net version 4.0 (So actually EFW is 4.40)
- SQL server 5.1
- MySQL for VS 1.1.4
- MySQL Connector 6.4.4

I have added a new field in a table that is already in the model,
when trying to update the model from the database, it won't update
actually, when prompted "Choose Your Database Objects and Settings", I can't expand the tables and views.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've noticed is that the EF model wizard won't appear if I'm using NuGet because NuGet pulls the latest version of all packages but my VS plugin was just installed once - there is no error when this happens; you get prompted for a connection and then no wizard appears. Here's the scenario:

1. I'm using MySQL Connector version 6.6.3 that I installed with MySQL Server
2. NuGet updates my driver package in the project to 6.9.8 on build
3. Wizard stops working because 6.6.3 != 6.9.8

To correct this I removed the MySQL references from NuGet and added them from my local machine. Now they are the same version as MySQL Connector and everything magically works again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: which package we have to check in references? MySql.Data(8.0.21.0)  & MySql.Data.Entity.EF6(6.9.10.0) & MySQL Connector version 8.0.21 please guide asap Thank you in advance